# PHP Code not executing on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

The following script is running on my localhost without any problems. It creates a json file that I request using AJAX to build a table in my front end. However, when I put it on my Ubuntu VM, which runs apache 2 and php 5.5 (json module is installed) it doesn't create the json file, the result being that my table is empty.

```
<?php
$arr = scandir('.\lehre\test');
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    if($arr[$k] == "." || $arr[$k] == ".."){
        unset($arr[$k]);
    }
    $fp = fopen('files.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr));
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

PS: Other PHP Elements, like the include statement work.
EDIT: I don't get any error msg. I use the forward slash notation within any other path declaration

Comment: Try to use **slashes** instead of **antislashes** for the `scandir` path

Comment: use `/` instead of `\\` on Linux systems

Comment: doesn't seem to fix it :(

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: `../` used for backward directory

Comment: Im not getting any error msg. That's the problem. The file simply is not created

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it your development environment is a Windows machine I'm guessing, which makes use of back slashes (`\`) when referencing directory paths. However on UNIX systems (Ubuntu in your case) the system uses forward slashes (`/`).

Good news however, even though the Windows system uses backslashes, running PHP scripts in Windows will recognise both back slashes and forward slashes as the same, so you can use the one without having to change it every time you run the script in a different OS.

TL;DR: Use `/` instead of `\`. It'll work on both Windows and Ubuntu.